# mpfr_init2 precision

Tags: c, mpfr

```
mpfr_t x;
mpfr_init2(x, prec);
```

According to the doc, what init2 does is to initialize a mpfr x, set its precision to be exactly some bits and its value to NaN.

Can anyone explain how do we decide how many bits do we need for the second argument in the init2 function? So that we don't need to allocate bits more than we need, or allocate bits less than we require.

Say we at most want to represent a number with 1024 digits behind the decimal point (e.g. 0.xxxx...xxx), this number's value is between 0 and 1, as I'm trying to implement an arithmetic coding encoder.

Comment: Is that 1024 decimal digits or 1024 binary digits?  I think that if it's decimal digits, you'll need to multiply 1024 by log2(10) and round up; if it's binary digits, use 1024.  But I've not used MPFR seriously — this is based on a casual reading of the [GNU MPFR manual](https://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/mpfr.html) (and [Initialization functions](https://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/mpfr.html#Initialization-Functions) and [variable conventions](https://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/mpfr.html#MPFR-Variable-Conventions)).

Comment: See [Number of Digits Required For Round-Trip Conversions](https://www.exploringbinary.com/number-of-digits-required-for-round-trip-conversions/). Essentially, to ensure that `d` significant decimal digits roundtrip across a binary conversion to `b` bits unchanged, you need to use `b = ceil( d * log2(10) ) + 1` bits. For `d = 1024` for example this gives [`b = 3403`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ceil%28+d+*+log2%2810%29+%29+%2B+1+where+d+%3D+1024) bits required.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I believe what you mentioned is basically equals to the comment from dxiv?

Comment: Yup — differently expressed but the same basic idea.

Comment: @dxiv what does it mean by round-trip a number?

Comment: @StephenFong Here, round-trip means converting from one format to another, then back to the  original format. In this case, convert the decimal number to binary representation, then back to decimal. If the number has no more than 1024 decimal digits, you convert it to binary representation using 3403 bits, then convert it back to decimal you are guaranteed that the end result matches the original number exactly.

Comment: @dxiv where's the difference between the two formulas in that page?

Comment: @StephenFong I count more than two on that page, and they are well explained each.